# Query XML Node Value by Node Attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a xml node that is stored as an xml datatype in a sql server column.  For example my xml column data is:

```
<fields>
<field id="StudentName">John Smith</field>
<field id="StudentID">1310021003</field>
<field id="SchoolName">Little Kid Elementary School</field>
</fields>
```

I want to retrieve the StudentID.  When I run the script below I get null.

```
select MyColumnName.value('(/fields/field/@StudentID)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as StudentId from MyTable
```

[bonus question] - I would also like to query the table by studentid if possible, for example: `select * from MyTable where MyColumnName.value('(/fields/field/@StudentID)[1]', 'varchar(20)') = '1310021003'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this would be test environment:

```
declare @MyTable table (MyColumnName xml)

insert into @MyTable 
select '<fields>
<field id="StudentName">John Smith</field>
<field id="StudentID">1310021003</field>
<field id="SchoolName">Little Kid Elementary School</field>
</fields>' union all

select '<fields>
<field id="StudentName">John Smith</field>
<field id="StudentID">2343343434</field>
<field id="SchoolName">Little Kid Elementary School</field>
</fields>'
```

To fetch data from xml, use `value()` function:

```
select
    MyColumnName.value('(fields/field[@id="StudentID"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as StudentID
from @MyTable
```

output:

```
StudentID
-----------
1310021003
2343343434
```

To filter by xml data, use `exist()` function

```
select
    *
from @MyTable
where MyColumnName.exist('fields/field[@id="StudentID" and text()=1310021003]') = 1
```

output:

```
MyColumnName
-----------
<fields>
    <field id="StudentName">John Smith</field>
    <field id="StudentID">1310021003</field>
    <field id="SchoolName">Little Kid Elementary School</field>
</fields>
```